# Is there a way to declare a new MongoDB model from existing MongoDB model in Node.js and Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an existing model defined with Mongoose that looks like this.

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: Array, default: []},
  userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},

  //Admin
  assignee: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},

  ... // has more than 50 properties

  flyerProvided: Boolean,
  lockboxOrdered: Boolean,
  lockboxTrackingInformation: String
}, {
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true
  },
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true
  }
});
```

What I want to achieve is to define a new Mongoose model for storing deleted product.
So instead of deleting a product from the Products collection, I want to move the product to `ArchivedProducts` collection

But instead of copying all the properties(more than 56) of ProductSchema, is there an easy way of using or extending the Product model?